# Обработка и вставка JSON данных в HTML

Tags: json

Есть таблица:

```
<tr class="odd gradeX panel panel-default info">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
```

в табличке 7 столбцов нужно чтобы в нее вставлялись данные поочереди в каждое `<td>`пришедшие от сервера в формате JSON, вот сам json:

```
{1:новоеЗначение, 2:новоеЗначение, 3:новоеЗначение, 4:новоеЗначение, 5:новоеЗначение, 6:новоеЗначение, 7:новоеЗначение}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перебираем свойство `children`:

```js
let tr = document.querySelector('.odd'),
    json = JSON.parse`{"1": "One", "2": "Two", "3": "Three", "4": "Four", "5": "Five", "6": "Six", "7": "Seven", "8": "Eight"}`;

Array.from(tr.children).forEach((td, i) => td.innerHTML = json[i + 1]);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="odd gradeX panel panel-default info">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: а можешь сделать на JQuery это?

Comment: @other спасибо и на этом!

Comment: @rodgers, в жиквери переделать очень легко, но зачем, если нативно и так работает?

Comment: да спасибо я уже переделал,просто не знал нативных функций этих, но расчехлился